# I would like to reopen this question (and ask people to actually read it)

Tags: discussion

The question is [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/113606/does-flash-have-any-future-on-linux-should-i-keep-on-making-games-with-flash-gi?noredirect=1#comment198652_113606) where I ask about the status of ActionScript 3 and Flex, asking whther there is, somewhere, a maintainable port (compatible). Where and how is that an *opinion based* question? Even when an answerer had an upvote for interpreting my question like they did (and I edited the question according to, say, got upvotes and thought it would be helpful for future users).

Please: The question body is **clear** about the issues & questions I have: they are technical and ask for 3rd party compatible ports with current Flex and AIR. There's no place for subjectivity in my question: either a maintained and compatible 3rd party exists port, or it does not exist.

I reedited the question. Could this be opened again?

Comment: I picked the close reason based on the title, fwiw, even though the body is (I think) off-topic due to asking for tech recommendations. I wouldn't be opposed to reopening it if the rest of the community agrees though, especially if the title is edited as it doesn't seem to quite match what you ask for anyhow.

Answer (score 2):

The [rules](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) suggest:

> To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where …
>
> - every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”

And here is essentially your question:

> Is there a (trusted 3rd party) community making a good port (good stands for compatibility) of those newer versions to Linux-based OSs? Or is Flash/Flex/AS3 actually dying?

IMHO, this is basically asking for a *list of one* very specific resource, where each answer is equally valid. In the long term, this has not much value for the site as 1) the technology is dying and 2) the community can change and thus make the would be accepted answer irrelevant.

This is why I believe this question should remain closed.